# How to pass the state of button object to another class when the tableview is in edit mode in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a tableview controller which consists of a button with an image on it and 2 labels. When I change the tableview to edit mode, I want my button to perform an action i.e such that when I click on my button in edit mode it should change its image. I have an editcontroller class when the didselectrow of first table is clicked it opens a new class i.e editcontroller.

In this controller class, I have a switch button. When the button image of the first tableview is changed to 'OFF' the the switchbutton in the editcontroller should also changed to 'OFF' and when the switchbutton of the editcontroller is changed to 'ON' then the button image should change to 'ON'.

This is my first tableview code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    appDelegate = (StopSnoozeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    TAlarmCell *cell =(TAlarmCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[TAlarmCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        mimageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        mimageButton.frame=CGRectMake(10, 20, 20, 20);   
        mimageButton.tag = 1;     
        [mimageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
        [mimageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected]; 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mimageButton];   
        [mimageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeMapType:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    }

    [appDelegate.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

     return cell;
}
```

In the editing code I have done this code

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [mTableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];
    if (editing)
    {
        [mimageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeMapType:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
        editimage = YES;
        [self.mTableView reloadData];


    }
    else {

        editimage = NO;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
        if (appDelegate.snoozearray)
        {
            [appDelegate.snoozearray release];
        }
        appDelegate.snoozearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
        [Alarm getInitialDataToDisplay:[appDelegate getDBPath]];
                [self.mTableView reloadData];
    }

}
```

This is my imagebutton action code

```
-(void)changeMapType:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath =[self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview]]; 

    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row; 
    NSLog(@"row...%d",row);
    appDelegate.changeimagetype = !appDelegate.changeimagetype;
    sender.selected = appDelegate.changeimagetype;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is not totally clear, but I get the idea of what you want to achieve.

You should use [NSNotification defaultCentre].

This is how it works. Suppose I have a class A, in which I have a button X, which I want to change its text when in my another class B. I click to change Button.

So these are the steps:

**1)In viewDidLoad of A**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ChangeButton) name:@"Change Button" object:nil]
```

**2) In Dealloc of A**

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

**3) In B..when you click to change Button after that put this line**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Change Button" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

**In the end, ChangeButton method (in A) will be called when click button is done in B make sure you define a method ChangeButton in A**.

Post a notification when the switch value changes and then in the other view, you will get that notification..and then change the button in respond to notification.

Comment: i have never worked with NSNotification.Could you please help me on how to do this through NSNotification or do you have any sample code

Comment: Shubhank, i have edited my question .Please can u check my question.My problem is when my tableview is in edit mode the selector is not called and the image does not change